# Generate REST API from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, azure, rest, api

Is it possible to generate a REST API from an existing SQL Server database?

I'm using Visual Studio and SQL Server on Azure.

How would I do this?

Comment: It's not that wise to expose your database (CRUD operations, I guess) to the external world. You better place an application server in between.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this. But you can achieve in two ways

(i) Using external applications like [DreamFactory](https://blog.dreamfactory.com/creating-a-microsoft-sql-server-api-in-less-than-5-minutes-with-dreamfactory/)

(ii) Write your own code to interact with SQL using c# with any entity framework, or even using javascript language

Comment: You may use LogicApps for this, or embed the C# wiring into a Function app. I was looking into this myself today, incredible that this does not exist as a functionality from SQLServer itself!